Problem initializing PLL as clock NUCLEO-H563ZI
I am trying to initialize the clock with PLL as system clock.
The code I used is the following
#include <stdio.h>
#define RCC_BASE    0x44020C00     // Base address of Reset and Clock Control
#define RCC_CR *((volatile unsigned int *)(RCC_BASE+0x0)) //Value of Reset and clock control register
#define RCC_CFGR1 *((volatile unsigned int *)(RCC_BASE+0x01C)) //Value of Reset and clock configruation register 1
#define RCC_CFGR2 *((volatile unsigned int *)(RCC_BASE+0x020)) //Value of Reset and clock configruation register 2
#define RCC_PLL1CFGR *((volatile unsigned int *)(RCC_BASE+0x028)) // Value of Reset and clock PLL clock source register 1
#define RCC_PLL1DIVR *((volatile unsigned int *)(RCC_BASE+0x034)) // RCC PLL1 dividers register

int clc_config(void){
 // Define clock as HSI and wait confirmation
  RCC_CR |=1;
  RCC_CR = 0x2b;
  RCC_CR |= (3<<3);
  while((RCC_CR & 1UL<<1)!= 1UL<<1);
 // Power interface and voltage regulator scaling
  
 // Flash prefetch anf latency 
  
  
  
    
 /*
   Prescalers
      1.rcc_hclk (prescaler = 1)
      2.pclk1 (prescale = 1)
      3.pclk2 (prescale = 1)
      4.pclk3 (prescale = 1)
*/
  //RCC_CFGR2 &= (0xFFFF8888)<<4; 
  
  // PLL Configure
  RCC_PLL1CFGR |= 1; // PLL source = HSI
  RCC_PLL1CFGR |= 1<<3; // In frequency range 4-8 MHz
  RCC_PLL1CFGR |= 1<<16; //Enable PLLp
  RCC_PLL1CFGR |= 1<<10; // PLLM = 4
  RCC_PLL1DIVR |= 0x010101F9; //n = 250,p,q,r = 2
  
  // PLL Enable 
  RCC_CR |= 1<<24;
  while(((RCC_CR & (1UL<<25)) == 0));
 
  // Select clock source and check status
  RCC_CFGR1 |= 0x3;// select PLL1 as clock source
  while((RCC_CFGR1&0x3<<3)== 0x3<<3);
  
  return 0;
 
}

The tutorial I am following is #1. Intro to STM32F4 Register Based Programming || Clock Setup || LED Blinking || NO HAL, his is a different board.
Although I found another image in the Reference Manual RM0481 of the STM32H563ZI MCU which gave flowchart for PLL init.

I tried moving the clock source selection up, but it didn't help.
What am I doing wrong?
While debugging, I am not able to move past this while loop:
 while(((RCC_CR & (1UL<<25)) == 0));


At least you cannot expect that the registers are zero when you start ORing bits that you want turned on.
If you want a register to have exactly some value you want, then just write that value.
The line that simply ORs the PLL multiplier etc will leave the register with incorrect settings which is not what you want.

Hi, I updated my code still didn't work, stuck at the same problem. I have attached the changed part below.
// PLL Configure
RCC_PLL1CFGR = 0;
RCC_PLL1CFGR |= 1; // PLL source = HSI
RCC_PLL1CFGR |= 1<<3; // In frequency range 4-8 MHz
RCC_PLL1CFGR |= 1<<16; //Enable PLLp
RCC_PLL1CFGR |= 1<<10; // PLLM = 4
RCC_PLL1DIVR = 0x010101F9; //n = 250,p,q,r = 2

@gaganchopra Why not look at examples that work? Like the STM32 HAL for your MCU?
